# Magento dynamic tax

Tags: magento

We have some products that the tax varies depending on the tax.
So we created tax class for products :

- Taxe class 1 ( Products 0-100$ )
- Taxe class 2 ( Products 100$ + )

That works well, my only problem is when to product is discounted, we need to change the tax class depending on the price of the item.

Anyone did something similar?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a nice thing to need to be doing... Depending on how you setup the discount, you could change the tax class at the same time (e.g. Data Flow Import using product special price attributes and product tax class). Or you could create a custom module and override the Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation class and make it behave you would like.

Comment: Tax varies depending on tax???